# breaking out of a loop in Julia

Tags: for-loop, julia, break

I have a `Vector` of `Vector`s of different length `W`. These last vectors contain integers between 0 and 150,000 in steps of 5 but can also be empty. I am trying to compute the empirical cdf for each of those vectors. I could compute these cdf iterating over every vector and every integer like this

```
cdfdict = Dict{Tuple{Int,Int},Float64}()
for i in 1:length(W)
    v = W[i]
    len = length(v)
    if len == 0
        pcdf = 1.0
    else
        for j in 0:5:150_000
            pcdf = length(v[v .<= j])/len
            cdfdict[i, j] = pcdf
        end
    end
end
```

However, this approach is inefficient because the cdf will be equal to 1 for `j >= maximum(v)` and sometimes this `maximum(v)` will be much lower than 150,000.

My question is: how can I include a condition that breaks out of the `j` loop for `j > maximum(v)` but still assigns `pcdf = 1.0` for the rest of `j`s?

I tried including a `break` when `j > maximum(v)` but this, of course, stops the loop from continuing for the rest of `j`s. Also, I can break the loop and then use `get!` to access/include `1.0` for keys not found in `cdfdict` later on, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: you could initialise your cdfdict with `1` as the default value, so that even if you break it doesn't matter.

Comment: this is almost the same as using `get!` after the loop...

Comment: I think that @TasosPapastylianou's solution is best.  But, you may be underestimating how fast loops are in Julia.  Looping from 0 to 150,000 by 5s and filling in with a pre-set value of 1.0 will take a trivial amount of time.

Comment: @amrods not really, you'll just have an initialisation for the "row" before the `j` for-loop. Also, your `pcdf=1.0` doesn't do anything ... you probably meant to do something else there.

Comment: I see now. The idea for `pcdf = 1.0` is to assign 1 to vectors in `W` with no elements, implicitly assuming that an empty vector has the same cdf as a vector of zeros.

Comment: If the intention is to assign all `j` in `0:5:150_000`, using a matrix (i.e. an Array{Float64,2}) of size `(length(W),length(0:5:150_000))` would be a better idea. Initially filling such a matrix to `1.0`s is easy and should take care of tail of CDF when `maximum(v)` is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, this answer details an implementation which fills an Array instead of a Dict.

First to create a random test case:

```
W = [rand(0:mv,rand(0:10)) for mv in floor(Int,exp(log(150_000)*rand(10)))]
```

Next create an array of the right size filled with 1.0s:

```
cdfmat = ones(Float64,length(W),length(0:5:150_000));
```

Now to fill the beginning of the CDFs:

```
for i=1:length(W)
    v = sort(W[i])
    k = 1
    thresh = 0
    for j=1:length(v)
        if (j>1 && v[j]==v[j-1])
            continue
        end
        pcdf = (j-1)/length(v)
        while thresh<v[j]
            cdfmat[i,k]=pcdf
            k += 1
            thresh += 5
        end
    end
end
```

This implementation uses a `sort` which can be slow sometimes, but the other implementations basically compare the vector with various values which is even slower in most cases.

Comment: This answer is a little sideways from the question and not explained in detail, so if needed, I will edit in details by need and questions in comments.

Comment: what about cases in which `v` contains repeated values?

Comment: Since going with an Array was marked as the answer, I will give another implementation with an Array which might be better in some cases - see below.

Answer (score 2):

`break` only does one level. You can do what you want by wrapping the for loop function and using `return` (instead of where you would've put break), or using `@goto`.

Or where you would break, you could switch a boolean `breakd=true` and then break, and at the bottom of the larger loop do `if breakd break end`.

Comment: `@goto` is far more clear than `if breakd`, and should be strongly preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another `for` loop to set all remaining elements to 1.0. The inner loop becomes

```
m = maximum(v)
for j in 0:5:150_000
    if j > m
        for k in j:5:150_000
            cdfdict[i, k] = 1.0
        end
        break
    end
    pcdf = count(x -> x <= j, v)/len
    cdfdict[i, j] = pcdf
end
```

However, this is rather hard to understand. It would be easier to use a branch. In fact, this should be just as fast because the branch is very predictable.

```
m = maximum(v)
for j in 0:5:150_000
    if j > m
        cdfdict[i, j] = 1.0
    else
        pcdf = count(x -> x <= j, v)/len
        cdfdict[i, j] = pcdf
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer gave an implementation using an Array which calculated the CDF by sorting the samples and filling up the CDF bins with quantile values. Since the whole Array is thus filled, doing another pass on the array should not be overly costly (we tolerate a single pass already). The sorting bit and the allocation accompanying it can be avoided by calculating a histogram in the array and using `cumsum` to produce a CDF. Perhaps the code will explain this better:

Initialize sizes, lengths and widths:

```
n = 10; w = 5; rmax = 150_000; hl = length(0:w:rmax)
```

Produce a sample example:

```
W = [rand(0:mv,rand(0:10)) for mv in floor(Int,exp(log(rmax)*rand(n)))];
```

Calculate the CDFs:

```
cdfmat = zeros(Float64,n,hl);  # empty histograms
for i=1:n                      # drop samples into histogram bins
  for j=1:length(W[i])
    cdfmat[i,1+(W[i][j]+w-1)÷5]+=one(Float64)
  end
end
cumsum!(cdfmat,cdfmat,2)       # calculate pre-CDF by cumsum
for i=1:n                      # normalize each CDF by total 
  if cdfmat[i,hl]==zero(Float64) # check if histogram empty?
    for j=1:hl                 # CDF of 1.0 as default (might be changed)
      cdfmat[i,j] = one(Float64)
    end
  else                         # the normalization factor calc-ed once
    f = one(Float64)/cdfmat[i,hl]
    for j=1:hl
      cdfmat[i,j] *= f
    end
  end
end
```

(a) Note the use of `one`,`zero` to prepare for change of Real type - this is good practice. (b) Also adding various `@inbounds` and `@simd` should optimize further. (c) Putting this code in a function is recommended (this is not done in this answer). (d) If having a zero CDF for empty samples is OK (which means no samples means huge samples semantically), then the second `for` can be simplified.

See other answers for more options, and reminder: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil* (Knuth??)